# Making a Free Response Quiz from text file

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm new to java and I working on this project to answer questions from a text file in random order. **NO MULTIPLE CHOICE** In the end it has count how many questions you got wrong. In the code you have to make a class called QAndA, with "a" as anwser and "q" as question in the data fields. Then at the end of that class make a toString() method to return "a" and "q". I will show that below.

```
class QAndA{
    String q;   //question
    String a;   //answer
    QAndA(String q, String a){
        this.q = q;
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getQ(){
        return q;
    }
    public String getA(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your answer: ");
        a = input.next();
        return a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return q;
    }
}
```

All there is to fix is just taking a question one at a time from the file and inputting the answer to see if its right. Also we have to use an ArrayList class with the QAndA objects. Example: ArrayList theNameoftheArray = new ArrayList();

Here is what the text file is suppose to look like:

Q: How do you call a general binary relationship that describes an activity between two classes?
A: association

Q: Defining multiple methods with the same name as long as their parameter lists are different is called?
A: overloading

Q: Write a statement that assigns the value true to the first element of the array butterfly.
A: butterfly[0] = true;

Q: When the return type of a method is an array, it actually returns?
A: a reference to the array

Q: True or false (T/F)? Constructors have the return type void.
A: F

Any help will be appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Actually stackoverflow shouldn't be a place to ask for full solutions for programs - anyway as you are new here -> here is my mini solution (without appropriate error handling!)

```
package at.mad.max;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
public class QandAMain {

    static class QAndA {
        String q; // question
        String a; // answer
        public QAndA(String q, String a) {
            this.q = q;
            this.a = a;
        }
        public String getQ() {
            return q;
        }
        public String getA() {
            return a;
        }
    }

    public static String readAnswerFromConsole() {
        System.out.println("Enter your answer: ");
        return new Scanner(System.in).next();
    }

    public static List<String> readFileFromResourceLineByLine(String fileName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        URL resource = QandAMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
        if (resource != null) {
            return Files.readAllLines(new File(resource.toURI()).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Q: (.+[^A:]) A: (.+)");
        List<String> lines = readFileFromResourceLineByLine("q_and_a.txt");
        List<QAndA> qAndAs = new ArrayList<QandAMain.QAndA>();
        lines.forEach(l -> {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(l);
            if (m.find()) {
                qAndAs.add(new QAndA(m.group(1), m.group(2)));
            }
        });
        Collections.shuffle(qAndAs);
        for (int i = 0; i < qAndAs.size(); i++) {
            QAndA qa = qAndAs.get(i);
            System.out.println("-- Question ("+(i+1)+" of "+qAndAs.size()+"): --\n"+qa.getQ());
            String userAnswer = readAnswerFromConsole();
            if (userAnswer != null && qa.getA().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswer.trim())) {
                System.out.println("Shiiish\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nope\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

You need to place a file with the above mentioned questions and answers in the resource path - in my example I called the file "q_and_a.txt".

You get following output:

```
-- Question (1 of 5): --
True or false (T/F)? Constructors have the return type void.
Enter your answer: 
F
Shiiish

-- Question (2 of 5): --
How do you call a general binary relationship that describes an activity between two classes?
Enter your answer: 
association
Shiiish

-- Question (3 of 5): --
When the return type of a method is an array, it actually returns?
Enter your answer: 
a pointer
Nope

...
...
```

Comment: Thank you!! Next time I'll do better with my questions.